Maui Geolocation - position changed event
I'm using the microsoft example code for Geolocation and listening for continuous location change. I've included a counter to discover how often the app receives GPS data. The result is curious. Walking down my garden 40m it doesn't register a change in location and I receive no GPS updates. Driving in the car the change of location event is raised and I get a burst of 3-50+ samples; and probably every 30-100m when the accuracy says its within 8m. Neither is very good if you are trying to pin point a location. It's like the phone caches the samples then dumps them to the app when the event is triggered.
Two questions:

Is there a way to change the distance that triggers the changed location event so that I get data every few meters?

In the GeolocationListeningRequest what is the purpose of the TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) and is it needed is continuous listening as the microsoft page is a little ambiguous? I have tried it with and without and it made no difference.


I wondered whether the issue was that the app receives GPS samples faster than the VM binding to the page could update quick enough. I put a breakpoint into the Geolocation_LocationChanged() and proved that no events were being raised and when an event occured samples arrived in bursts.
The relevant bits of code are:
public async void OnStartListening()
{
    try
    {
        MyBearing = "0";
        MyCourse = "0";

        Geolocation.LocationChanged += Geolocation_LocationChanged;

        var request = new GeolocationListeningRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.High, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    public void Geolocation_LocationChanged(object sender, GeolocationLocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Process e.Location to get the new location

        // read the gps data
        var myLocation = e.Location;
        
        // update labels
        Altitudelabel = $"{myLocation.Altitude:0} m";
        AccuracyLabel = $"{myLocation.Accuracy:0} m";
        GPSMyBearing = $"{myLocation.Course:0}  ° ";
        MySpeed = $"{((myLocation.Speed) * 3.6):0.##} Km/h ";     //Speed is in m/s so x 3.6 to get Km/h

// MORE CODE HERE



        // Keep a count of the number of GPS data received and update the label
        i = i + 1;
        MyMessage3= $"GPS samples Rx {i}"; // testing the listening

    }


What device are you testing with, and what is the specific API version?

Samsung galaxy A8 on android 9

Is there a way to change the distance that triggers the changed location event so that I get data every few meters You can try to change the Accuracy and try again.

I've done that already. I've tried default, high and best.

Have you tested it with other devices?

I've tested on two Android phones and taken them on a long drive. Starting and stopping the GPS listening multiple times creates multiple samples being received when the locationchanged event is raised. The locationchanged event distance trigger varies depending on the accuracy being received. At 3m accuracy samples are every 80m. At 40m accruracy samples are every 150m. Therefore best you can hope for is within 80m which is not good. Any suggestions of how to trigger more sample locations say in the last 250m would be gratefully received.
